# bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'left'

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pca

I am trying to perform a principal component analysis and plot the scree plot using matplotlib function `bar()`. I observe this error while running the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scaled_data = preprocessing.scale(data.T)
pca=PCA()
pca.fit(scaled_data)
pca_data = pca.transform(scaled_data)
per_var = np.round(pca.explained_variance_ratio_*100, decimals=1)

labels = ['PC'+str(i) for i in range(1,len(per_var)+1)]
plt.bar(x=range(1,len(per_var)+1), height=per_var, tick_label=labels)
plt.xlabel('Principal Component')
plt.ylabel('Percentage of Variance Explained')
plt.title('Scree Plot')
plt.show()
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'left'
```

Comment: Can you indicate how you defined `plt` in your code ?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
plt.bar(range(1,len(per_var)+1), per_var, tick_label=labels)
```

The parameters x and height don't need to be named. 
I had the same problem and that solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

As per [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html):

> **Note**
>   In addition to the above described arguments, this function can take a
>   data keyword argument.
>   If such a `data` argument is given, the following
>   arguments are replaced by `data[<arg>]`:
>
> - All arguments with the
>     following names: ‘bottom’, ‘color’, ‘ecolor’, ‘edgecolor’, ‘height’,
>     ‘left’, ‘linewidth’, ‘tick_label’, ‘width’, ‘x’, ‘xerr’, ‘y’, ‘yerr’.
> - All positional arguments.